# Unable to install scala on phusion/baseimage

Tags: scala, docker, ubuntu-14.04

Hi I am unable to install scala on a phusion base-image

https://gist.github.com/geoHeil/f52bb118303157cafd77e0c49db3de71

The image contains java8
but the installation of scala fails with

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of scala:
 scala depends on libjansi-java; however:
  Package libjansi-java is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package scala (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Which normally would indicate java is not installed.

But java_home is set correctly and java-executable is in the path.

Comment: No, it doesn't indicate java isn't installed. It says `libjansi-java` is not installed.

Comment: Sure. But a java -version
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode) works when connected to the container

Comment: That doesn't matter.

Comment: ok so what is wrong with my java installation?

Comment: Read the dpkg message again. Jars in debian (and ubuntu) are package into lib<something>-java, so you're missing a dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a problem with the 10.5 version of the deb file. 11.6 works like a charm